# Laravel Schema Builder, setting field description

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to add a description/comment to the sql field with laravel's schema builder. Just like in drupal?

Comment: [No it's not](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/93) and probably won't in the future. You have to fall back to SQL

Comment: awee.. calling a DB::statement(); after a Schema::table(); does work at the moment;

Comment: I've added an answer... If you have a better solution (e.g. slightly simpler SQL) feel free to suggest an edit or just leave a comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that you can add comments, but it doesn't seem to be documented. [This Laracasts post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-comment-on-table-column-using-schema-builder/replies/6198) shows how – by adding a "comment" property to the end of the line.

Using their example,

```
 Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
 {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('product_name')->comment = "Product name column";
    $table->timestamps();
  });
 }
```

As it turns out – just testing now – you can actually use the more typical function syntax for that, so for example,

```
$table->string('product_name')->comment('Product name column');
```

...similar to setting `->default(...)` or `->nullable()`. Some people might prefer that style for consistency.

This seems to work great as of Laravel 5 and using MySQL. It might be a recent improvement.

Answer (score 1):

[Descriptions / comments are not supported by the schema builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/93) and probably won't in the future. You have to fall back to SQL:

*Assuming you use MySQL*

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments();
    $table->text('username');
    $table->text('password', 60);
});

DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `password` `password` VARCHAR(60) COMMENT 'password hash');
```

Comment: i just skipped the Schema::create call and used only the DB::statement to create and modify the table. I'ts working and i guess it doesn't have any problems doing so.

Comment: Sure, the create is just for other people who might want to add the description while creating. And to make it clear that there's such a table which such a column ;)

Comment: i don't really like adding comments to everything i do but, i do hoping comments will help some other person reading the code.